# KeyboardAvoidingView on Android with AdjustResize keep the button at the bottom React native

Tags: android, react-native

**Description**

I've implemented the KeyboardAvoidingView from React Native, on iOS is working as expected, but on Android there's an issue with the elements of the View, I have a button at the bottom of the screen and I'd like it to stay there when the keyboard shows up only the textInput should go up when the keyboard is invoked.

TLDR: I'm trying to get the button to stay bottom while avoiding panning the entire View on Android

current behavior with adjustResize:

[image]

**What I've already tried**

By looking around there were some solutions that solved the problem, but caused other issues:

- In AndroidManifest.xml I changed `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, but this caused the entire View to pan upwards instead the View should remain static:

> **"adjustPan"**: The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

- I tried to hide the button on the event `'keyboardDidShow'` and make it reappear on `'keyboardDidHide'`, but during the animation the button is visible for the entire time
- Position absolute on the button didn't solve the issue

**Example of the code implemented**

```
        <SafeAreaView>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={style}>
                  <Text/>
                  <TextInput/>
                </View>
              </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
              <Button/>
          </SafeAreaView>
```

**Android manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".activityname"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

**Environment**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.2
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8559U CPU @ 2.70GHz
    Memory: 52.02 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 13.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 24, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

**Conclusion**

Is there any way to keep the button at the bottom, while keeping the entire view static?

Thanks for reading and sorry for the long post

Comment: What's the styling?

Comment: the styling are just flex: 1 on all components, although the keyboard avoiding view has the following props:
`<KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={[flex: 1]}
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "padding" : null}
        enabled={true}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({
          ios: getStatusBarHeight(),
          androi: 0
        })}
      >`

Comment: I don't think this is possible without setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. It seems adjustResize is applied to the entire screen and not just the view.

Comment: Yes I agree for this reason I was just wondering if there was a solution, Thanks!